# Do we use the Spring web applicaiton code present in GitHub, direclty in an environment like DEV, QA or PROD?

Tags: spring, github, ant, tortoisesvn, environment

Currently I use Tortoise SVN as VCS for changes to my Spring application. We then build the code using ant and then deploy the change to DEVELOPMENT environment and then if the code working we move to subsequent environments.
However, when we are using GitHUB as the VCS, is it any different and we can use the code that is present in GitHub and directly push in to DEV, QA or PROD environments directly?

or

Do we deploy only the .ear file after building it to the respective environments?

Currently I am using Tortoise SVN, for my spring application for build and deployment.
However, I would like to know the process for GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do we deploy only the .ear file after building it to the respective environments?

That is the recommended practice considering:

- any deliverable built from versioned sources should *not* be versionned itself
- since the deliverable is not versioned in the (Git) repository, Git itself would not be used for deployment.

Git is the version control tool, which differs from GitHub: GitHub is the Git repository hosting server, which provides additional services.

GitHub might be used for deployment, through [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) and its [deployment workflows](https://github.com/features/actions). But the all program is still in beta.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! So by GitHub Actions or Deployment worflows, we build the .ear file and deploy it to the desired environment, right?

Comment: @user3809696 That is the idea, all from GitHub servers.